# Insert personalized link into html tag in email

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have a database of customers who purchased my products. Now I want to send them each an email asking for their reviews on the products they bought. Here is the email [template](http://codepen.io/vkhu/pen/PqyEdr)

```html
<span style="display:none !important; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; color:transparent; height:0; width:0;">Xin chào Trang, bạn nghĩ sao về cuốn truyện Xứ cát vừa mua? Đừng quên chia sẻ cảm nhận của mình với những bạn đọc khác trên Bookism.net nhé!</span>

<table style="max-width:600px;min-width:450px;margin:auto;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      
      <!--logo-->
      <a href="http://bookism.net/">
        <table style="background:#0e303d;width:100%;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);overflow:hidden">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding:1em;">
              <table style="max-width:300px;text-align:center;margin:auto;">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/t4cx03z9z/image.png" style="max-width:100%;height:auto;">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </a>
      
      <!--Main-->
      <table style="margin-top:1em;background:#FAF9F5;padding:.1em 2em;max-width:100%;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            
            <!--Greeting-->
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <p style="font-size:1.2em;font-weight:900;">Xin chào Trang,</p>
                  <p>Bạn nghĩ sao về cuốn truyện <span style="font-style:italic">TÊN TRUYỆN</span> vừa mua? Đừng quên chia sẻ cảm nhận của mình với những bạn đọc khác trên Bookism.net nhé!</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            
            <!--Book + ask for review-->
            <table>
              <tr>
                <!--cover-->
                <td style="padding:1em;">
                  <table style="max-width:300px;background:#EBE9E5;padding:.2em;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a href="http://bookism.net/gian-truyen/truyen/dau-truong-sinh-tu-55.html"><img src="http://bookism.net/img/upload/images/product/Books/Sci%20Fi/Cong%20chua%20mat%20trang%20Cinder/front.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto"></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
                
                <!--ask for review-->
                <td style="vertical-align:top">
                  
                  <!--title + author-->
                  <p>
                    <a href="http://bookism.net/gian-truyen/truyen/dau-truong-sinh-tu-55.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:rgba(0,0,0,.6);margin-bottom:3em;">Tên của truyện</a><br/>
                    <a href="http://bookism.net/gian-truyen/truyen/dau-truong-sinh-tu-55.html" style="text-decoration:none;color:rgba(0,0,0,.4)">Tên tác giả</a>
                  </p>
                  
                  <!--CTA-->
                  <a href="http://bookism.net/gian-truyen/truyen/dau-truong-sinh-tu-55.html#ratebyuser">
                    <table style="padding:.8em;width:10em;text-align:center;background:#1A5970;border-radius:10px;color:#fff;margin:auto;">
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <span>CHO ĐÁNH GIÁ</span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      <!--please show image-->
      <table style="color:#999;text-align:center;margin-top:1em;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Nếu các bạn không xem được ảnh, xin hãy bấm "Luôn hiển thị ảnh từ bookism.net@gmail.com" ở phía bên trên email.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      <!--unsubscribe-->
      <table style="color:#999;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Hãy thêm <a href="mailto:bookism.net@gmail.com" target="_blank">bookism.net@gmail.com</a> vào địa chỉ liên lạc để không bỏ lỡ bất kì thông báo nào.</p><p>Bọn mình hi vọng bạn thấy thích nội dung bức email này. Nếu bạn cảm thấy không muốn nhận những email tương tự từ Bookism.net, xin bạn hãy vào form <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/197UShwoMgsildGRsI5ugi49e3LlBWVmb819gPn1v1so/formResponse">này</a> để bọn mình biết. Rất xin lỗi vì đã làm phiền bạn.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is I have a lot of customer, and if I have to manually edit the link leading to the product, the product image link for each customer, it will take forever!

Is there anyway I can assign a link to a specific customer and have gmail automatically load the link corresponding to that customer's email address?

Comment: Is there no third party service that can automate that? I'm clueless about anything backend related.

Comment: I recommend reading into [PHP.net](http://php.net)

Answer (score 0):

You could get all email adresses from the database in a Collection and using a placeholder in the html text.

I saved my html-email-template in a resource dictionary and had an email-placeholder like this:

```
<a href="mailto:{0}">{0}</a>
```

you can than loop throught the dictionary and use `string.Format(...)` to fill the placeholder.
Pseudo-Code

```
foreach(var emailAddress in emailAddresses)
{
  SendMail(string.Format(emailTextFromResourceDictionary, emailAddress));
}
```

Edit: this is for using C# / asp.net (the resource dictionary and code notation etc. but should similarly work in other languages since the concept stays the same)